# Can I write OCaml in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ocaml

I find a plug-in called  Visual ML

http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?contrib=62

but I can't find the download link

Is there other plug-ins I can use?

Comment: This plugin is a `proprietary License`. **I** don't know of any. But you can find plugins for `eclipse` and `netbeans`

Comment: Thank you Elcid,I have been using OcalDE,but I'm still very curious about how to write OCaml in VisualStudio,Could you tell me where I can download it :)

Comment: I tried to follow the link but didn't work.. Google search didn't give anything either. Went on their website [here](http://tech.motion-twin.com/ocaml.html) but found nothing

Comment: e, i didn't find the download link too. may be the project is died.

Comment: Notepad++ has support for OCaml out of the box, the language setting is called CAML